# I cannot insert many id into the db because it only permits last INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, sql-insert

```
$AddRecord6 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_t_records(PerformanceID,QuizID,ProjectID,ExamID,AttendanceID,fuck) 
        VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),LAST_INSERT_ID(),'1')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

I cannot Use Multiple LAST_INSERT_ID() it only permits the first LAST_INSERT_ID() and I cannot use the MAX(id) because it is not good

Comment: So, you want to store LAST_INSERT_ID() into multiple fields of the same table?

Comment: The PerformanceID,QuizID,ProjectID are all Foreign Keys, I inserted records for Quiz Table, Performance Table Project Table, Exam Table And Attendance Table, So in the $AddRecord6 Query I will insert all the LAST INSERTED ID of the Tables but it only permits 1 Table

Comment: You do know right that LAST_INSERT_ID() is exactly what it says, the _last_ inserted auto-increment id. So all the values for it will be equal; you are inserting identical values into the fields of this table, based on _only one_ previous query

Comment: Thank you very much sir. So how can I make it  unidentical?

Comment: I'll give you the full query dir

Answer (score 0):

Get the last insert ID in PHP first!

```
$lastId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Comment: how did you get on?